# How create instance for datrow dynamically using Activator

Tags: model-view-controller, generics, reflection, datarow, activator

i want to create instance for datarow using activator like this

```
 dataItem = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```

while i using this code i got exception

No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Answer (score 0):

[The only constructor for DataRow is internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.datarow.aspx). A DataRow is created by call to [DataTable.NewRow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx).